# Switch between ArcGIS and R changes my shapefile projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, r

Not the best practice, but somethimes I need to change between ArcGIS 10.6 and R (version 3.6.1) to process my shapefiles. For example, I want to read my shapefile in R -> process it -> export it back to ArcGIS.

But, the projection of my data changes in between: **I read the shapefile in one coordinate system, export it in same CRS, but ArcGIS reads it as different projection**.

Let's see on watershed dataset:

I work on Finland watersheds. In ArcGIS, it has projection `EUREF_FIN_TM35FIN`, **WKID 3067**

[image]

After loading this file to R, the projection is a string:

```
library(rgdal) 
library(sp)

setwd("U:/rawData/Finland/watershed/valuma")

watershed = readOGR(dsn = "U:/rawData/Finland/watershed/valuma",
                    layer = "Jako3")

proj4string(watershed)
# [1] "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

This is how the this projection string should look like [reffering to  spatialreference.org:](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3067/proj4/)

```
+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

But, after exporting this file to new .shp:

```
# Add the stand geometry
writeOGR(obj    = watershed, 
         dsn    = getwd(), 
         layer  = "watershed_no", 
         driver = "ESRI Shapefile",  
         overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

**ArcGIS now reads this projection as Custom projection (even not listed within ArcGIS library!!!) as `UTM_Zone_35_Northern_Hemisphere`!!**

[image]

I have tried to transform my data to correct CRS before exported in R:

```
watershed.t <- spTransform(watershed, CRS("+init=epsg:3067"))
```

But, ArcGIS still reads this as a `Custom` CRS. **How to define my `CRS` in R, to be correctly read in ArcGIS? Or how can I avoid its change between softwares?**

EDIT:

I have tried both suggestions:

1. Specify the `watershed@proj4string@projargs` by adding `+init=epsg:3067`

   ```
   watershed@proj4string@projargs <- paste0('+init=epsg:3067 ', watershed@proj4string@projargs)
   ```
2. transform my data using `spTranform` and specify epsg:

   ```
   watershed.t <- spTransform(watershed, CRSargs(CRS("+init=epsg:3067")))
   ```

but they both produce the same output: `Custom projection UTM_Zone_35_Northern_Hemisphere
Authority: Custom` in ArcGIS 10.6.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I would fret over this. It likely does not make a bit of difference in the resulting processing but, just test it to make sure. This is probably due to ArcGIS not having an exact UTM definition for the GRS80 spheroid. If it really concerns you just define a custom projection in ArcGIS, that matches the expected proj4 string, and assign it when you open the shapefile in the software. It is quite easy managing projections in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I've had [similar issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327997/crs-validity-and-proj-versions) with R (raster), QGIS, and EPSGs 4151 and 4283, which have the same proj string. The EPSG code with the smallest number was getting assigned first on write.

I've been fixing it with something like

```
x@proj4string@projargs <- paste0('+init=epsg:XXXX ', x@proj4string@projargs)
```

before write, which is ugly but does the trick. Bear in mind the issues with case sensitivity in the linked question.

This should all resolve itself as newer versions of GDAL and PROJ make it into the R spatial ecosystem.

In the meantime, have you tried using the `arcgisbinding` package to handle I/O instead of writing to disk? Might help. https://r-arcgis.github.io/

Comment: thank you @obrl_soil for a nice suggestion and for `arcgisbinding` package suggestion, I will try this on! But, I still can't make it work using your answer. Do you have any other suggestions? or have I specified it wrongly? Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

When transforming the data in R in your last step, try using the `CRSargs()’ instead of only CRS.

```
watershed.t <- spTransform(watershed, CRSargs(CRS("+init=epsg:3067")))
```

Comment: Thank you @Jelle, I have tried this, looks promising but I still get the not specified output. Maybe some other suggestions?